# React and checking condition after passing function through props

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

I'm fighting with my app since long time and slowly there is progress however I have still problem with one thing
I want to pass function thought props from Form Component to List component, after that I wish to check if button add was clicked if yes then I wish to launch function getMovie() inside List component and send another request to json database. with edit and remove it works as there are in same component, with adding button it is a bit more tricky.

the problem is that if I write just

```
else if (this.props.addClick) {
                this.getMovie();
        }
```

it's keep sending requests to database over and over

below is my code

Form Component

```
class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            type: '',
            description: '',
            id: '',
            movies: [],
            errors: "",
        }
    }

handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/`;
        if (this.state.name != "" && this.state.type != "" && this.state.description != "") {
            axios
                .post(url, {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    type: this.state.type,
                    description: this.state.description,
                    id: this.state.id,
                })
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        movies: [this.state.name, this.state.type, this.state.description, this.state.id]
                    })
                })
                .then(this.setState({
                isButtonRemoveClicked: true
            }))
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                errors:"Please, Fill all forms above"
            })
        }

    }

return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie" onChange={this.handleChangeOne}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type of movie" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo}/>
                    <textarea placeholder="Description of the movie"
                              onChange={this.handleChangeThree}></textarea>
                    <input id="addMovie" type="submit" value="Add movie" ></input>
                    <p>{this.state.errors}</p>
                </form>
                <List removeClick={this.handleRemove} editClick={this.editMovie} addClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        )
```

List Component

```
class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            movies: [],
            isButtonRemoveClicked: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovie()
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.isButtonRemoveClicked === true) {
            this.getMovie();
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    isButtonRemoveClicked: false
                })
            }, 10)
        }
        else if (this.props.addClick === true) {
                this.getMovie();
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
    }


    getMovie = () => {
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies`;
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(res => {
                const movies = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    movies: movies,
                })
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your main objective is to call function in child component from parent component, then you can use refs.

Example in your code :-

```
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        type: '',
        description: '',
        id: '',
        movies: [],
        errors: "",
    }
} 
handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies/`;
        if (this.state.name != "" && this.state.type != "" && this.state.description != "") {
            axios
                .post(url, {
                    name: this.state.name,
                    type: this.state.type,
                    description: this.state.description,
                    id: this.state.id,
                })
                .then(res => {
                    this.setState({
                        movies: [this.state.name, this.state.type, this.state.description, this.state.id]
                    })
                })
                .then(
                this.list.getMovie();   // call child function here
                this.setState({
                isButtonRemoveClicked: true
            }))
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                errors:"Please, Fill all forms above"
            })
        }

    }

return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Movie" onChange={this.handleChangeOne}/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type of movie" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo}/>
                    <textarea placeholder="Description of the movie"
                              onChange={this.handleChangeThree}></textarea>
                    <input id="addMovie" type="submit" value="Add movie" ></input>
                    <p>{this.state.errors}</p>
                </form>
                <List
                    ref={list => this.list=list }  // Create ref here
                    removeClick={this.handleRemove}
                    editClick={this.editMovie}
                    addClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        )
```

And in list component no need to use componentDidUpdate getMovie() call.

```
class List extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        movies: [],
        isButtonRemoveClicked: false,
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getMovie()
}

getMovie = () => {
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/movies`;
    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => {
            const movies = res.data;
            this.setState({
                movies: movies,
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

Comment: it works! I gotta study about refs as I understand how they works but I haven't had opportunity to use them it practice:) Thank you so much my friend:)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical ;)
You're start loading data from componentDidUpdate() ... data loads, componentDidUpdate is fired again, again...

Don't handle events this way.

Comment: that's why I was thinking to set some condition like "`if (this.state.isButtonRemoveClicked === true)`" just for this props function,
hmm so what other way do you suggest? as I tried many things and it didn't work out until someone here on forum suggested to put function into componentDidUpdate() and just set conditions when it is supposed to be launched

Comment: It's a (ugly) workaround - it works but you're not 'clearing flag' after use ;)  Simply set to false to avoid cycle.

Comment: hmm set to false you mean something like this? because it doesn't work... `else if (this.props.addClick) {
                this.getMovie();
                this.props.addClick === false;
        }`

Comment: componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.isButtonRemoveClicked === true) {
            this.setState({
                    isButtonRemoveClicked: false
            })
            this.getMovie();
        }
    }

recommended way?
wrap both component into 'container' (read about difference), in short:

`<Movies>` (with CRUD handlers) renders `<List>` (or `<Loading>`) and `<Form addHandler={this.handleAdd.bind(this)} />`. in `Form` use passed handler with `this.props.addHandler` directly or from internal handler.

List items have to use ids calling handlers.

Comment: hmm with refs it works but I'm gonna do some research about creating containers (still beginner here:() and then try to remake my code to more "clean" way, anyway thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are handling events in an overcomplicated manner. Why don't you lift props from inside the List component and just trigger the desired behaviour in the Form?. For example:

```
class List extends React.Component {

  handleAddClick() {
    this.props.onAddClick()
  }

  handleEditClick() {
    this.props.onEditClick()
  }

  handleRemoveClick() {
    this.props.onRemoveClick()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleAddClick()}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleEditClick()}> Edit</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleRemoveClick()} > Remove</button>
      </div>
  })
}
```

and

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  getMovie() {
    // Make AXIOS request
  }

  handleAdd() {
    this.getMovie();
  }

  handleRemove() {
    // REMOVE CODE
  }

  handleEdit() {
    // EDIT CODE
  }

  render() {
    <form>
      {/* Form elements */}
      <List
        onAddClick={() => this.handleAdd()}
        onRemoveClick={() => this.handleRemove()}
        onEditClick={() => this.handleEdit()}
        />
  </form>
    }
}
```